# Google Speech API: the requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-speech

I am attempting some simple tests on the Google Speech API, and when my server makes a request to this url (below), I get the `404. that's an error` response. Not sure why.

https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=[MY_API_KEY]

The body of my request looks like this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "encoding": "LINEAR16",
        "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
        "enableWordTimeOffsets": true,
        "speechContexts": [{
            "phrases": ["Some", "Helpful", "Phrases"]
        }]
    },
    "audio":{
        "uri":"gs://mydomain.com/my_file.mp3"
    }
}
```

And here is the response:

[image]

As you can see, that is a valid resource path, unless I'm totally mistaken about something (I'm sure I am): https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize

***Update 1:***, Whenever I try this with the Google API explorer tool, I get this quota exceeded message (even though I have not yet issued a successful request to the API).

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota metric 'speech.googleapis.com/default_requests' and limit 'DefaultRequestsPerMinutePerProject' of service 'speech.googleapis.com' for consumer '[MY_API_KEY]'.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/[my_project_id]/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

***Update 2:*** Interestingly, I was able to get some 200 ok's using the Restlet client, but even in those cases, the response body is empty (see screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a test by using the exact URL and Body content you added to the post, however, I was able to execute the API call [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTn2Z.png).

I noticed that if I add some extra character to the URL, it fails with the same 400 error since it doesn't exist. I would suggest you to verify that the URL of your request doesn't contain a typo and that the client you use is executing the API call correctly. Also, ensure that your calling code is not encoding the url, which could cause issues given the colon `:` that appears in the url.

I recommend you to perform this test by using the [Try this API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize) tool directly or [Restlet client](https://client.restlet.com/) which are the ones that I used to replicate this scenario.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! I tried both of the tools you recommended and have updated the post with the results if you don't mind taking a look. What did your response from the Google API explorer and Restlet look like?

Comment: You are getting no results as the [encoding](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding) configuration might be incorrect. In my case, I converted the file to a FLAC encoding, as recommended in the [Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices), and changed the parameters `"encoding": "FLAC"` and `"sampleRateHertz": 44100`. Additionally, you can use the [Troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/support#troubleshooting) guide in case your transcript is not returned.

Comment: You may want to check the [Multiple channels](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multi-channel) property as well.

Comment: Basically, your response should look like the one included in the [Quickstar](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol#make_an_audio_transcription_request) which has the same structure of the response I received. You can take a look on [this link](http://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/recognize#response-body) that contains a detailed description of each response section. Finally, I suggest you to verify that you are using the right credentials as well as you are not exceeding the [API quotas](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas)